# Determine dynamically linux OS architecture

Tags: linux, unix, architecture

Is there is a way to know dynamically Linux architecture, whether it `x86-64` or `x86`?

Comment: Why exactly do you ask? You should try to write portable code....

Comment: Architecture of the CPU, OS or your app? Because you can run both 32 and 64 bit apps on a 64-bit Linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Posix standard [uname](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/uname.html) function (implemented in the [uname(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/uname.2.html) syscall) is dynamically giving you the information about the CPU. You probably want the  `machine` field.

<sup>Caution about x86-64 kernels running a 32 bit program (e.g. a 32 bits Debian distribution `chroot`-ed in a 64 bits Debian, or perhaps a 32 bits ELF binary running on a 64 bits system); I have no idea what they give in that situation; I would imagine some `x86_64` in that case, since the kernel does not really know about the binaries and `libc` of the system.</sup>

See also the Linux specific [personality(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/personality.2.html) syscall.

Comment: I meant eg. a Debian 32 bits distribution on a 64 bits Linux kernel (e.g. `chroot`-ed in a Debian 64 bits distribution)

Comment: Right. In fact, those odd situations (x86 ELF on x86-64 kernel) are the only reasons to call uname dynamically at all. Ideally, check a more general macro or heuristic (eg _LP64) to detect 32/64 as appropriate on SPARC, POWER, etc too.

Comment: +1 for personality(2). Never seen that before. See also setarch(8) for more information where it confirms that PER_LINUX32 sneakily causes uname to lie!

Answer (score 1):

Google is your friend: http://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/Architectures/

You want to test for the macros `__amd64__` and `__i386__`.  Ideally, you don't test the macros at all and write correct, portable code.

Comment: sorry, i forgot to say, that it should be dynamic

Comment: Why? To find what kernel your 32-bit binary is running on? It's not a dynamic property for an x86-64 binary, of course. Read `man 2 uname`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use lscpu command to list characteristics about CPU.

Comment: It might be simpler to run the single `uname(2)` syscall instead of `popen` (or the many equivalent syscalls: `pipe`, `dup2`, `fork`, `execve` at least).